# put query results into an object

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am using php and postgresql.

I need a function that:

connects to a db if not already connected
run the query safely
put the results into an object

For example:
I do a query that is 'select * from test'. I get back 2 rows...There are three columns in 'test' (id,fname,lname).

I have an object named $ep. I want to be able to put the column name results into the object and also put the values into the object. So I could do a var_dump of $ep->fname and it would show me an array with two results.

I don't want to hardcode the column names into my function. I want it to be dynamic. So regardless of what table or columns I request it will put everything into the object for me.

Comment: Have you tried looking at PDO?

Answer (score 1):

An [Object Relational Mapper (ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) can give you a lot of the functionality you described (and more). Take a look at:

- Doctrine: http://www.doctrine-project.org/
- Propel: http://www.propelorm.org/

Here's what Propel code looks like:

```
$book = BookQuery::create()->findPK(123); // retrieve a record from a database
$book->setName('Don\'t be Hax0red!'); // modify. Don't worry about escaping
$book->save(); // persist the modification to the database

$books = BookQuery::create()  // retrieve all books...
  ->filterByPublishYear(2009) // ... published in 2009
  ->orderByTitle()            // ... ordered by title
  ->joinWith('Book.Author')   // ... with their author
  ->find();

foreach($books as $book) {
  echo  $book->getAuthor()->getFullName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

**pg_fetch_object**

read the documentation

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-object.php

example

```
<?php 
$database = "test";
$db_conn = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=$database");
if (!$db_conn): ?>
    <H1>Failed connecting to postgres database <?php echo $database ?></H1> <?php
    exit;
endif;

$ep = pg_query ($db_conn, "SELECT * FROM verlag ORDER BY autor");
$row = 0; // postgres needs a row counter other dbs might not 

while ($data = pg_fetch_object ($ep, $row)) {
    echo $data->fname;
    $row++;
}

?>
```

Comment: -1 its crazy, what wrong with it, please highlight so i can also learn.

Comment: This seems to work. I had to remove the $row from the while loop because I was getting an error message.

Comment: i wonder some one is desperately doing on my ID. i am here to help not enmity!::)

Comment: I put what you did in a function. Now how do I make it so I can access the object outside the function?

Comment: two ways , either you pass $data from $data = pg_fetch_object ($ep, $row) to other function you are calling or make $data as local variable meaning , you can define $data at the top of portion, once its executed , you can access this data from any where. does this make sense if yes please voteup and accept as answer.

Comment: @JapanPro - I have tried global $data but it is not working. I don't want to pass it to another function.

Comment: @kaith, dont stop responding after getting answered. just update whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to construct your own array or object, and then loop through the results, adding each of them to the array/object as you went.

There are some packages which include this functionality, like [ezSQL](http://justinvincent.com/docs/ezsql/ez_sql_help.htm).